Show that if $f(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ and $f(0) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ using Riemann sums.
I am trying to show that if $$ f(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt $$ and $ f(0) = 0 $, then $ f(x) = 0 $ for all $ x $ in a neighborhood around $ 0 $.
It is given that $f$ is continuous on $R$.
I want to derive a contradiction by assuming that for some point $ a < 1 $ we have $ f(a) \neq 0 $.
To approach this, I would like to use the definition of Riemann sums instead of the Mean Value Theorem or the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Define the Riemann sum for $ f(x) $ on the interval $ [0, a] $ as:
$$
   R_n(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{(i-1)a}{n}\right) \cdot \frac{a}{n}.
   $$

When $ x = a $, the Riemann sum should also tend to $ 0 $:
$$
   R_n(a) = 0.
   $$


I would then apply contradiction assuming $ f(a) $ isn't zero, and use the continuity of f to derive a contradiction.
Edit:
Here is an attempt at a sketch of my idea.
Proof: We will show that if $ f(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt $ and $ f $ is continuous, then $ f(x) = 0 $ for all $ x > 0 $.

We start with the condition that $ f(0) = 0 $ since:
$$
   f(0) = \int_0^0 f(t) \, dt = 0.
   $$

For $ a > 0 $, we can express $ f(a) $ using Riemann sums:
$$
   f(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left( \frac{ia}{n} \right) \cdot \frac{a}{n}.
   $$

We can recursively replace $ f\left( \frac{ia}{n} \right) $ with its own Riemann sum:
$$
   f\left( \frac{ia}{n} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n} f\left( \frac{jia}{n^2} \right) \cdot \frac{ia}{n^2}.
   $$
Substituting this back into the expression for $ f(a) $, we get:
$$
   f(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} f\left( \frac{jia}{n^2} \right) \cdot \frac{ia}{n^2} \right) \cdot \frac{a}{n}.
   $$

Continuing this process recursively, we can express $ f(a) $ in the limit as:
$$
   f(a) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i_1=1}^{n} \sum_{i_2=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{n} f\left( \frac{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k a}{n^k} \right) \cdot \frac{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k a}{n^k}.
   $$

As $ k $ increases, the term $ \frac{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k a}{n^k} $ approaches $ 0 $. By the continuity of $ f $, we have:
$$
   \lim_{k \to \infty}f\left( \frac{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k a}{n^k} \right) \to f(0) = 0.
   $$

Thus, for sufficiently large $ n $ and $ k $, we can see that the contributions from each term approach $ 0 $:
$$
   f(a) = \sum_{i_1=1}^{n} \sum_{i_2=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{n} 0 \cdot \frac{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k a}{n^k} = 0.
   $$

Since $ f(a) $ is expressed as a sum that approaches $ 0 $, we conclude that $ f(a) = 0 $ for all $ a > 0 $. Thus, $ f(x) = 0 $ for all $ x > 0 $.


I am personally suspicious of point 6.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
